# Output only the last value

Tags: oracle-apex

into a query I have a data field "Nodes". In this field there are values in different lengths e.g..:

test1;test2;test3;test4;

Now I want, that I get only the last value.
That means in this case the following should be output:

test4;

That means I would have to determine the last but one ";" and delete everything in front of it so that only the last value is displayed

Excample:
select substr('node_5_1571123383558;response_7_1589984037984;', 1, instr('node_5_1571123383558;response_7_1589984037984;', ';') -1)
from dual

The example gives me the first value from the left. But I need the last value from the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like the ones below

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR ('exciting;',
               CASE REGEXP_COUNT ('exciting;', ';')
                   WHEN 1
                   THEN
                       1
                   ELSE
                         INSTR ('exciting;',
                                ';',
                                1,
                                REGEXP_COUNT ('exciting;', ';') - 1)
                       + 1
               END)
  FROM DUAL;

Output: exciting;

SELECT SUBSTR ('node_5_1571123383558;response_7_1589984037984;',
               CASE REGEXP_COUNT ('node_5_1571123383558;response_7_1589984037984;', ';')
                   WHEN 1
                   THEN
                       1
                   ELSE
                         INSTR ('node_5_1571123383558;response_7_1589984037984;',
                                ';',
                                1,
                                REGEXP_COUNT ('node_5_1571123383558;response_7_1589984037984;', ';') - 1)
                       + 1
               END)
  FROM DUAL;

Output: response_7_1589984037984;
```

Comment: What surprises me a little is the error message ORA-01428.

The error occurs if only one value is available. Example:

SELECT SUBSTR ('exciting;', INSTR ('exciting;', ';', 1, REGEXP_COUNT ('exciting;', ';') - 1) + 1) FROM DUAL;

Comment: Just updated the query to handle the case when there is only one value

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^;]*;$' ) AS last_value
FROM   table_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( value, INSTR( value, ';', -1, 2 ) + 1 ) AS last_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'one;' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'two;three;' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'four;five;six;' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> ```
> | LAST_VALUE |
> | :--------- |
> | one;       |
> | three;     |
> | six;       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cf1806fdd26dabe7879066a14a37bb7)*